# Is there a way to determine for which receiver (or for which URI) DownloadManager sent intent when completed?

Tags: android, android-intent, download-manager

I have a bunch of files to download (simultaneously, if possible). So I register N BroadcastReceivers for `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` and enqueue N requests.

Okay, everything is going better than expected until I receiving Intent broadcasted by DownloadManager. Yes, EVERY receiver receives this Intent.

Hmm. I can fetch a row for a specific download ID (which `DownloadManager.enqueue` returns) and check if the status of the file with the URL linked to this receiver is `STATUS_SUCCESSFUL`, do what I need and then unregister receiver.

But... You know, it isn't the best way to do this.

Is there a way to determine URL or some other info from intent or does DownloadManager only notify my when something is done? Or how do I handle multiple downloads at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intent has `extra_download_id` field which are equal to ID of one of enqueued requests.

[How to identify which file triggered Download_Complete intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713115/how-to-identify-which-file-triggered-download-complete-intent)